# JWPlayer 7 error "cannot load m3u8 crossdomain access denied" chrome only win 10

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-domain, m3u8, jwplayer7

On pc windows 10 Firefox and Edge loads ok. In chrome only! "cannot load m3u8: crossdomain access denied"

JWPlayer HTML code

`<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer('Player');
 playerInstance.setup({
  primary: 'flash',
  file: 'http://example/playlist.m3u8',
  image: "//example/example.png",
  title: "example"
});
</script>`

Crossdomain.xml

```
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from secure="false" headers="*" domain="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: what's jwplayer 7.x version?

Comment: Jwplayer `7.11.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response

I have found the answer to my question the URL was missing the port number (http://exsamle.com**:0000**/my/stream.m3u8)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the CORS header of stream files  ..../playlist.m3u8 and it's needed when the player works in HTML5 Mode (on new releases of Chrome the  Flash plugin has blocked by default)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

It's a mechanism similar to Flash.

You can test your CORS HLS streams on hls.js demo page: http://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/

about CORS: https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i tested the m3u8 stream on the site you recommended (http://video-dev.github.io/hls.js/demo/) in chrome the stream loads good Hmmmm

Comment: if you try only with 'file' parameter it works? ex.  playerInstance.setup({ file: 'http://example/playlist.m3u8' });

Comment: `var playerInstance = jwplayer('Player');
 playerInstance.setup({
  file: 'http://-/playlist.m3u8',
});` now it works in edge only!

Comment: do you have jwplayer 'premium' license?